# How can you exit a program from a nested exception?

Tags: python, exception, nested, exit

Why does the following code not exit immediately from `exit()`?

```
x=1

try:
    x/1
    try:
        x/0
    except:
        print(2)
        exit()
except:
    print(1)

print(3)
```

Output:

```
2
1
3
```